# Transaction too large exception android

Tags: android, xml

I have a activity which open to fragment and both fragment contain radio groups which contain drawable images as button.When activity is open is go back to previous activity and say transaction too large exception.Tghis exception shoes that it does not properly load drawable for radio button.

Residential_Commercial_Activity java:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_residential__commercial_);
    Firstopenfragment();
    SetToolbar();
    TypeCasting();

    //FOR BACK BUTTON ENABLED
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mNextActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //get data from map activity and also from this activity which button is clicked in the form of string and pass previous data and this activity data to next activity which is "Upload_Property_Activity"

            Intent next = new Intent(Residential_Commercial_Activity.this, Upload_Property_Activity.class);
            startActivity(next);
        }
    });


    mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Replace);

            if (checkedId == R.id.Commercial) {
                //calling fragment  Builder_Broker_Fragment
                CommercialFragment frag = new CommercialFragment();
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.Replace, frag, "Commercial");


                //  transaction.replace(R.id.frag1,frag);
                transaction.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (checkedId == R.id.Residential) {

                ResidentialFragment frag = new ResidentialFragment();
                FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.Replace, frag, "Residential");
                transaction.commit();
            }

        }
    });


}

private void Firstopenfragment() {

    ResidentialFragment frag = new ResidentialFragment();
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.Replace, frag, "Residential");
    transaction.commit();

}
```

residential_commercial xml:

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/appbartransparent"></include>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Backgroundimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@mipmap/background" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#2E7D32"
        android:text="Next"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/NextActivity" />



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/residential" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Gotit"
            android:textSize="23dp" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/RadioButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/first"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">


            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/Residential"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/for_sell"
                android:checked="false"
                android:button="@null"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/Commercial"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Residential"
                android:background="@drawable/commercialdrawable"
                android:button="@null"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />


        </RadioGroup>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/Replace"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">


        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation1"
    android:name="com.example.asad.homebuyerproject.NavigationBar"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigationdrawerwidth"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation" />
```

This activity opens to fragment and the layout of one of them whic opens when activity is open is:

fragment_residential:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
tools:context="com.example.asad.homebuyerproject.ResidentialFragment">


<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/ReplaceAreaCommercial"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/hosteldrawable"
        android:button="@null" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Residential"
        android:background="@drawable/housedrawable"
        android:button="@null" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Residential"
        android:background="@drawable/builderfloor"
        android:button="@null" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Residential"
        android:background="@drawable/penthousedrawable"
        android:button="@null" />


</RadioGroup>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="150dp"

    >

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/flatdrawable"
            android:button="@null" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/villadrawable"
            android:button="@null"

            />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/studioaprtment"
            android:button="@null" />


    </RadioGroup>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.asad.homebuyerproject, PID: 4082
              java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                  at android.content.res.XmlBlock.newParser(XmlBlock.java:71)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2672)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2467)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1128)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1128)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1128)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1128)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1128)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1128)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1128)
                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawa
     I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 26.116ms for cause Alloc
     I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 25.978ms for cause Alloc
     I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 25.225ms for cause Alloc
     I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 25.021ms for cause Alloc
     D/Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.StackOverflowError
     D/Error: ERR: exMsg=stack size 8MB
     D/Error: ERR: file=XmlBlock.java
     D/Error: ERR: class=android.content.res.XmlBlock
     D/Error: ERR: method=newParser line=71
      I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2(800KB)                                                                   AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 91MB/92MB, paused 7.924ms total 10.023ms
      I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 34(2608B)                AllocSpace objects, 1(21MB) LOS objects, 18% free, 70MB/86MB, paused 206us total 22.998ms
      D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
         at android.content.res.XmlBlock.newParser(XmlBlock.java:71)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2672)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2467)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1128)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1128)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1128)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1128)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1128)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1128)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2469)
         at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
         at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:182)
         at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:127)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:1128)
         at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:1032)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Res
      D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 15842836
     E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
       E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
              android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
                  at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                  at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
          Application terminated.
```

The fragment whichi want to open is:  [all are radio buttons with drawables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjYxe.png)

Comment: "Transnsaction too large exceptionn android" -- that is not the exception shown in your stack trace. Your stack trace shows a `StackOverflowError`. My guess is that you have created a `StateListDrawable` resource that refers to itself.

Comment: @CommonsWare Anyway, I doubt such an exception will ever be raised... or at least, I hope so. Editing the title so at least there's no typo.

Comment: @CommonsWare means..?

Comment: @ShehzadKhan I'm not sure "means..?" stands for "Which means?" or something like that, but please consider making full sentences.

Comment: @CommonsWare i ask what is state lsit drawer and how i resolve this issue..?

Comment: Just got the same error. Any leads?